# Check if password and username input match in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have made a little program that should ask you for your password and username. After you have entered your details it should check if the password and the username are correct. how do i approach and do that?

```
from tkinter import *
from getpass import getpass

def callback():
    print(E1)()

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

L1 = Label(top, text="Password")
L1.grid(row=1, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5,show="•")
E1.grid(row=1, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=3, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're importing the getpass module, but you're not using it.  Do you want to know how to use it, or do you want to use your own Tk code?

Comment: Well, where and in what form are you storing the correct password or correct password hash?  You need some way to access that information from your program.

Comment: yeah i would like to know how to use the getpass and i was thinking of storing the password and username in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that demonstrates the use of getpass and how to check a user supplied password against a hashed password. This ignores lots of issues such as salting the hash, appropriate places to store authentication data, how many users you need to support etc.

```
import getpass, hashlib

USER = 'ali_baba'
# hashlib.md5('open sesame').hexdigest()
PASSWORD_HASH = '54ef36ec71201fdf9d1423fd26f97f6b'

user = raw_input("Who are you? ")
password = getpass.getpass("What's the password? ")
password_hash = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()

if (user == USER) and (password_hash == PASSWORD_HASH):
    print "user authenticated"
else:
    print "user authentication failed"
```

If you don't want to store the user name in code, you could do this:

```
# hashlib.md5('ali_baba:open sesame').hexdigest()
AUTH_HASH = '0fce635beba659c6341d76da4f97212f'
user = raw_input("Who are you? ")
password = getpass.getpass("What's the password? ")
auth_hash = hashlib.md5('%s:%s' % (user, password)).hexdigest()
if auth_hash == AUTH_HASH:
    print "user authenticated"
else:
    print "user authentication failed"
```